# monotone Hermite interpolation

Tags: interpolation, approximation-theory

Is there a reason why in particular it is so popular to use monotone cubic Hermite interpolation compare to say, quadratic? I understand the the order of the accuracy gets better with a higher degree, but quadratic splines seem already good enough with second order globally. I wonder if there are other reasons...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is possible [to interpolate data exactly with $C^1$ quadratic splines](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-80/issue-5/Quadratic-spline-interpolation/bams/1183535831.full), this does not allow us to interpolate monotone data with monotone $C^1$ quadratic splines.

Consider one of the monotone example data sets [given to your previous Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/300872/3111), $(0,0), (1,0), (2,1), (3,1)$.  As with the monotone $C^1$ cubic splines, the only possible polynomial portions in the first and last subintervals are constants, so that to be $C^1$ on the middle interval imposes four conditions, the function and its derivative at both endpoints $x=1,2$.

While a (monotone) cubic polynomial can be constructed to meet those four conditions, it is impossible for any quadratic polynomial to have a derivative with two roots.

Comment: your answers are very helpful. Thanks a lot!