# Fritsch and Carlson is non-linear?

Tags: interpolation, approximation-theory

I was reading about this interpolation method and saw that it was mentioned that the algorithm is non-linear. What does that exactly mean? I am confused because I don't get what is "non-linearity" in this case. I have set of points, I go over each interval and find the slopes that need to be modified and modify them.  So I loop only once; is it not linear then?

Comment: The meaning is simply that the results cannot be expressed as a linear operator applied to the inputs.  Fritsch-Carlson is one of several algorithms for providing [a monotone cubic spline interpolating monotone data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_cubic_interpolation).

Comment: but why their operator is not linear? Because it is a straightforward(linear in my sense) operation. On each interval calculate $d_i=1/2(L1+L2)$, the if $\alpha_i,\beta_i$ are not in region reassign a new value to $d_i$. Where is non linearity?

Comment: Perhaps you have in mind the computational complexity, which is $O(n)$ in the number $n$ of data points.  However your question is in what sense "the interpolation method" is non-linear, and that's what I've answered.  Note that polynomial interpolation is a linear operator (obeys the superposition principle), but is not monotone (monotone data may yield polynomial fits with oscillations).  Piecewise linear (first-degree spline) interpolation is both linear and monotone preserving, but the cubic splines illustrate that as we move to higher degree/smoother fits, this breaks down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

However "straightforward" Fritsch and Carlson's proposed method for [Monotone Piecewise Cubic Interpolation (1980)](http://www.osti.gov/bridge/servlets/purl/6411580-QAxnRa/6411580.pdf) that preserve monotonicity may be, the mapping is not linear.

Linearity would imply that solutions exhibit the *superposition principle* in that on any common set of nodes $\{x_i\}$, the function $f$ which interpolates monotone increasing $\{y_i\}$,

$$ f(x_i) = y_i $$

and the function $g$ which interpolates monotone increasing $\{z_i\}$,

$$ g(x_i) = z_i $$

would add up to the function $h$ which interpolates $\{y_i + z_i\}$,

$$ h(x_i) = y_i + z_i $$

But it doesn't generally happen that $h = f + g$.  I think an example that illustrates this is for $\{x_i\}=\{0,1,2,3\}$, $y_0 = y_1 = 0, y_2 = y_3 = 1$, and $z_0 = 0, z_1 = z_2 = 1, z_3 = 2$.  If these data are added, the resulting $h(x) = x$ on $[0,3]$, which is not the sum $f(x) + g(x)$.

---

Here are some crude pictures of the three monotone cubic spline interpolants $f,g,h$ for the data above:

[image: monotone cubic spline interpolants]

Following the steps outlined [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_cubic_interpolation), the resulting splines are easily found.  The function $f$ must be constant on the first and last intervals, the function $g$ must be constant on the middle interval, and as already noted, $h(x)=x$.  To prove $h \neq f + g$ is suffices to inspect the middle interval, where clearly $h$ and $g$ are flat (without curvature), but the function $f$ has an inflection point and switches from concave up to concave down.

The monotone cubic splines are secretly cubic Hermite splines, where function values are specified by input data and slopes $m_i$ are chosen to ensure monotonicity (and continuity of the first derivative).  In the case of $f$ we have slopes $f'(0)=f'(1)=f'(2)=f'(3)=0$, while for $g$ we impose $g'(0)=g'(3)=1$ and $g'(1)=g'(2)=0$.  Since $h'(x) = 1$ identically, this gives a more concrete demonstration that $h \neq f+g$.

Comment: thanks. It is helpful of explaining that the linearity of the algorithm is associated with a linearity of the mapping. However, even if the algorithm is non-linear, as F&C, what are the drawbacks in this case? Is that harder to implement or it takes more time compare to linear? I guess plain cubic Hermite would be linear, so what?

Comment: It's drawbacks are not on implementation or time-performance, but rather in quality of the interpolant.  Using piecewise cubic curves one can interpolate the data with a $C^2$ (two continuous derivatives) solution, but losing monotonicity.  After F&C research has explored a number of strategies for preserving monotonicity but improving the interpolant, in particular obtaining a $C^2$ solution with little additional computation.  Raising the issue of "nonlinearity" is something of a proxy for questioning the F&C algorithm's intuitiveness.

Comment: I see, thanks. One more related question: I think it is not as easy to show the error estimates in this case and I have not seen that in F&C paper. But any idea what is the accuracy of the method?

Comment: Accuracy and "error estimates" implies there's an approximation involved.  As far as our discussion of F&C goes we have exact interpolation of data (monotone function values at distinct nodes), so I think if you want to ask about monotone approximation it would be best to frame that in a separate question.

Comment: but are not we approximating a function at a set of points? The interpolant in the approximation of the function which is sampled at those points. Thus, I should be able to say how difference the true function and interpolant at any point in between the nodes.

Comment: That notion of a "function which is sampled at those points" is not required by the Fritsch and Carlson algorithm, or others that interpolate a monotone data set with a monotone function.  You are welcome to try your hand at formulating such a question.